# symfony4: mysql in console command

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entitymanager

What is the best way to create mysql connection in the console command?

```
    $doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
    $em = $doctrine->getEntityManager();
```

I want to write my own queries, how you are making that?
Because in the symfony4 documentation it using doctrine.

I can use https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/database for example, but is it good practice?

Answer (score 0):

You always can write your own sql (which is hardly ever needed) with Doctrine.

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/245/how-to-execute-plain-sql-using-doctrine-in-symfony-3

However

```
$this->getContainer()
```

is not available within Commands. I would recommend to use autowiring.

```
/**
 * Command constructor.
 *
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager to access Doctrine
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(
    EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
) : void {

    $this->_entityManager = $entityManager;

    parent::__construct();
}
```

Also, Doctrine is really powerful so there might be a solution to your problem out-of-the-box.